# need to check oracle query executed from which machine

Tags: oracle

I am developer and stated working in oracle database also now i have one query that is for development environment we are using common user named `abc` having same credentials so in a team of ten people we are using this same user to log in to oracle database  that is `abc` user

so please advise lets say if i want to track that which oracle query is fired by which machine that s i want to tack the machine name from which the oracle query is fired , then how can i track that.

Comment: If you need to find out which user is running the query, stop using the same user account to run the query. Then you don't have to hack around trying to find another way to do it. If you're OK with using the same user account, you clearly don't need to know which user is executing the query.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks but i was thinking still there must be some way of detecting individual machine ip

Comment: What would that tell you? I can execute the query from your keyboard while you're getting coffee, and blame you for whatever goes wrong because it came from your computer, because you can't tell who is sitting at the keyboard from an IP address. If you need to identify the user, give them a user account with a password, and you'll know who ran the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create audit and look at audit trail, you may want to add a trigger to the AUD$ table to count logins, monitor for specific actions , or perform other security-related function

AUDIT_TRAIL = { none | os | db | db,extended | xml | xml,extended }